# How to pass multiple parameter in an object with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to send parameters to populate function of Mongoose JS.

```
.populate('friends', { username: 1, age: 1})
```

How should I pass these variables in an object? So I will call this function like:

```
.populate(populationVars)
```

Comment: What does `populationVars` look like?

Comment: That is  exactly what I wonder to know:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `apply` I suppose:

```
var populationVars = ["friends", { username: 1, age: 1}];
fn.populate.apply(null, populationVars);
```

Comment: I'm getting  TypeError: Cannot read property 'populate' of undefined in  node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2719:27   if (!utils.isObject(opts.populate)) {
    opts.populate = {};
  }

Comment: @Burak - That means `opts` is undefined.